# Android Intent To Open Google Maps Application At Explore Nearby Screen

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I want to directly open up Google Maps Application at the Explore Nearby Screen, e.g. Eat like this screenshot here

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14944627/Google%20Maps%20Application%20Image.png

I can open Google Maps Application using the following code

```
 String uri = "http://maps.google.com/";
 Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
 intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
 startActivity(intent);
```

But I want it to go directly to the Explore Nearby Screen which is reached by clicking on the Search Bar > Then click on the explore nearby > eat icon.

**I just want to automate the click steps by opening the google maps application and then clicking on the search bar > eat. So that the explore nearby eat google maps page is displayed to the user ... is this possible?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score -1):

yes you can use `Google Places API`.

Please add you data to following URL and pass it to your intent.

> String url=
>   "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere"
>
> You can check following URL for documentation: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search

Comment: Hi, I tried this but it is just opening up the application as normal, not at the places eat page.